# AntiForgery implementation in Asp.net Forms

Tags: asp.net, forms, httphandler, antiforgerytoken

I am developing an httphandler to process some requests in Web Forms (NOT in MVC).
How could I implement Anti Cross Site Scripting (like antiforgery in MVC)?
I want to know mre about the antiforgery mechanism in MVC.

Comment: All the useful classes/methods are either private, protected or internal so of no use outside of an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: http://anticsrf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access the Page, you can use the [ViewStateUserKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.viewstateuserkey.aspx) property of the Page. Here is an example of how to do this from within the page, but you will get the idea:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Validate whether ViewState contains the MAC fingerprint
    // Without a fingerprint, it's impossible to prevent CSRF.
    if (!this.Page.EnableViewStateMac)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "The page does NOT have the MAC enabled and the view" +
            "state is therefore vulnerable to tampering.");
    }

    this.ViewStateUserKey = this.Session.SessionID;
}
```

While the ViewStateUserKey is pretty safe, there are some short comes with this. You can read more about that [here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=62).

Comment: Thanks
I've also implemented these sections:
1- Checking http method to be POST.
2- Checking the UrlRefferrer to be the same domain name.
3- I will add your solution.

If a hacker changes his/her DNS during surfing the web application, could it be dangerouse or not?