# Preventing crf attacks on ajax requests in asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax, csrf

How can I prevent csrf attacks on ajax requests in a asp.net webforms application

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a token and keep it in Session["CSRF"] and render the same in HiddenField of everypage.

```
protected HiddenField CSRF { get; set; }

protected void page_load(object s, args[] e) {
    if(Session["CSRF"]!=null) {
        this.CSRF=Session["CSRF"];
    }
    else {
        Session["CSRF"]=Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.CSRF=Session["CSRF"];
    }
}
```

So whenever you send a request add it as a data parameter and check it in the server side code.

Pass this CSRF HiddenField id for every request.

For ASP.Net Ajax calls you could use `ViewState["CSRF"]`, since by default update panel will send the Page's viewstate also :)

[for jQuery ajax](http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=118)

```
var csrf_token = '<%= csrf_value %>';
```

The below code will add this token for all the ajax requests

```
$("body").bind("ajaxSend", function(elm, xhr, s){
if (s.type == "POST") {
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
}
});
```

Comment: And if you are using jQuery for ajax calls, you can always "print" the token client side using the method described [here](http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=118)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this link: [Preventing Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Attacks](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-(csrf)-attacks)

In short: anti-forgery tokens, which are provided as part of the ASP.NET MVC framework. Since however you are using webforms, it might be a little bit more complicated but it is possible to have an ASP.NET website running both webforms and MVC (or have a look at this answered question: [AntiForgery implementation in Asp.net Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3291695/375304)).

**EDIT:** Also, to protect jQuery calls, you could use an anti forgery token and print it client side (as described [here](http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=118):

```
var csrf_token = '<%= token_value %>';
$("body").bind("ajaxSend", function(elm, xhr, s){
   if (s.type == "POST") {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
   }
});
```

Comment: I have actually fixed csrf issues in rails and java. I'm new to asp.net and already read through the links you provided. Does the solution described in the stackoverflow post work with ajax requests too?

Comment: It depends on how you are doing your AJAX requests. Are they done via jQuery.ajax or are you using update panels or equivalent ?

Comment: We are not using jquery. It is plain ajax as described in http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp. All the nequests talk to a single aspx page invoking various actions.